# How to get a JSON object from a file and map it to a Java class using Apache Camel routes?

Tags: java, json, routes, apache-camel

I have created a RequestRoute which extends `RouteBuilder`:

```
@Component
public class RequestRoute extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file:input?noop=true").to(User.class);
}
```

And in the main class, I have added the route created above to Camel context:

```
  @SpringBootApplication
  public class DemoApplication {

  @SneakyThrows
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RequestRoute());
  }
```

}

How can I get a `JSON object` from a file inside the folder and transform it to a Class using `Camel` routes?

Comment: Convert JSON object to POJO is done by unmarshal. [Reference](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/data-format.html)

Comment: How about calling `process` method and inside of it use `ObjectMapper` to convert the JSON object to a Java class.

Comment: Yes, you can do the transformation in java way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do an unmarshal.

```
from("file:input?noop=true")
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, User.class)
```